# Resolve asynchronous function of Graphql not able to return data queried over Stardog server having rdf data

Tags: javascript, node.js, rdf, graphql, stardog

I am trying to query a stardog server using graphql below is my code.

```
import {
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLFloat
} from 'graphql';

import axios from 'axios';

var stardog = require("stardog");

let Noun = new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: "Noun",
      description: "Basic information on a GitHub user",
      fields: () => ({
          "c": {
       type: GraphQLString,
       resolve: (obj) => {
        console.log(obj);
          }
        }
     })
});

const query = new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: "Query",
      description: "First GraphQL for Sparql Endpoint Adaptive!",
      fields: () => ({
        noun: {
          type: Noun,
          description: "Noun data from fibosearch",
          args: {
            noun_value: {
              type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
              description: "The GitHub user login you want information on",
            },
          },
          resolve: (_,{noun_value}) => {
              var conn = new stardog.Connection();

              conn.setEndpoint("http://stardog.edmcouncil.org");
              conn.setCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx");
                conn.query({
                    database: "jenkins-stardog-load-fibo-30",
                    query: `select ?c  where {?s rdfs:label '${noun_value}'. ?c rdfs:subClassOf ?s}`,  
                    limit: 10,
                    offset: 0
                },
                function (data) {
                       console.log(data.results.bindings);
                       return data.results.bindings;
                });  
              }
            },
          })
      });

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query
});

export default schema;
```

Query is executed successfully and I am able to see the result on console but `return data.results.bindings;` inside `function(data)` is not returning this result to the `Noun` type system under the  `resolve: (obj) => {  console.log(obj); }`
and the `obj` returned is showing null instead of the result `bindings` returned from the query of GraphQL. It would be great if someone could help me to figure out what I am missing here.

Thanks in advance,
Yashpal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your query, the `resolve` function of `noun` field is an asynchronous operation (the query part). But your code is synchronous. So, nothing actually gets returned immediately from the resolve function. This results in nothing passed to the resolve function of `Noun` GraphQL object type. That's why you're getting null when you print `obj`.

In case of asynchronous operations in `resolve` functions, you have to return a promise object that resolves with your intended result. You can also use ES7 async/await feature; in that case, you have to declare `resolve: async (_, {noun_value}) => { // awaited code}`.

With [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), the code will look like below:

```
resolve: (_,{noun_value}) => {
  var conn = new stardog.Connection();

  conn.setEndpoint("http://stardog.edmcouncil.org");
  conn.setCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx");
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    conn.query({
      database: "jenkins-stardog-load-fibo-30",
      query: `select ?c  where {?s rdfs:label '${noun_value}'. ?c rdfs:subClassOf ?s}`,  
      limit: 10,
      offset: 0
    }, function (data) {
      console.log(data.results.bindings);
      if (data.results.bindings) {
        return resolve(data.results.bindings);
      } else {
        return reject('Null found for data.results.bindings');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, I have updated the code as per your suggestion but server is syntax error for new Promise((resolve, reject)) field, although I have installed promise package and put var Promise = require("promise");

Comment: Most probably you're not using ES6. I have replaced arrow function in the code. Let me know if you have syntax error now.

Comment: Thanks a million Ahmad finally I am able to run this with your guidance.:)

Comment: @Yashpal , glad to hear that. You may want to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: I am not able to get the resolved result for the query on GraphiQL UI while the console.log(obj);
                        
[ { c: { type: 'uri', value: 'spec.edmcouncil.org/fibo/FND/Arrangements/ClassificationSchemes/…; } }, 
{ c: { type: 'uri', value: 'spec.edmcouncil.org/fibo/FND/Arrangements/Quantities/…; } }]
                       
but in GraphiQL UI the result shows like: 
              
{ "data": 
{ "Noun": 
{ "c": 
[ "[object Object]", 
"[object Object]" ] } } }

Comment: @Yashpal, you should post a new question with that GraphiQL query problem.

Comment: here is the link for new questions, please provide your guidance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013315/need-to-resolve-rdf-form-result-in-graphql-type-system