# GraphQL query over stardog triplestore but not able to create type system for result

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, sparql, rdf, graphql-js

I am trying to query stardog server using GraphQL below is the code.

```
function getResult() {
  return {
    type: new GraphQLList(GraphQLString),
    description: "URI to get data on the people this person follows",
    resolve: (obj) => {
        console.log(obj);
      return obj;
    }
  };
}

let result = new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: "c",
      description: "Basic information on a GitHub user",
      fields: () => ({
          "c": getResult()
     })
});


const query = new GraphQLObjectType({
      name: "Query",
      description: "First GraphQL for Sparql Endpoint!",
      fields: () => ({
        Noun: {
          type: result,
          description: "Noun data from ",
          args: {
            noun_value: {
              type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString),
              description: "Noun returns the subclass nouns",
            },
          },
          resolve: (_,{noun_value}) => {
              var conn = new stardog.Connection();

              conn.setEndpoint("xxxxxx");
              conn.setCredentials("xxxx", "xxxx");
          return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    conn.query({
                      database: "xxxxxx",
                      query: `select ?c  where {?s rdfs:label '${noun_value}'. ?c rdfs:subClassOf ?s}`,  
                      limit: 10,
                      offset: 0
                    },
                    function (data) {
                        if (data.results.bindings) {
                          return resolve(data.results.bindings);
                        } else {
                          return reject('Null found for data.results.bindings');
                        }
                      });
                  })
              }
          },
        })
      });

const schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query
});

export default schema;
```

I am not able to get the resolved result for the query on `GraphiQL` UI while the `console.log(obj)`; inside `getResult` Function prints the result as follows:-

```
[ { c: { type: 'uri', value: 'spec.edmcouncil.org/fibo/FND/Arrangements/ClassificationSchemes/…; } }, 
{ c: { type: 'uri', value: 'spec.edmcouncil.org/fibo/FND/Arrangements/Quantities/…; } }]
```

but in GraphiQL UI the result shows like it doesn't come the same way

Comment: in GraphiQL UI the result shows like: 
{ "data": 
{ "Noun": 
{ "c": 
[ "[object Object]", 
"[object Object]" ] } } }                                                                                    can someone help me to find what I am missing here to resolve my result exactly the way it prints on console in getResult Function using console.log(obj)

Thanks in advance, 
Yashpal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Graphql to query Stardog server having rdf data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814916/using-graphql-to-query-stardog-server-having-rdf-data)

Comment: Yes but its an extension to that question because here I need help to get the result in GraphiQL UI same as what I have got in console.